# Enable Filtering and sorting in a protected sheet using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have created a workbook with protected sheets because I only need a very few columns as editable. Although I want to let the user to be able to sort and filter columns.

Google searches have failed me as of yet. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Depends on whether this is a `XSSFSheet` or not. If it is a `XSSFSheet`, then [XSSFSheet.lockAutoFilter(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockAutoFilter-boolean-) and [XSSFSheet.lockSort(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockSort-boolean-).

Comment: Hi Axel. It is an XSSFSheet. Although, lockAutoFilter and lockSort didn't work. It stays grayed out in the protected sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is a `XSSFSheet`, then [XSSFSheet.lockAutoFilter(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockAutoFilter-boolean-) and [XSSFSheet.lockSort(false)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockSort-boolean-) will set the properties for enabling auto-filtering and sorting in protected sheets.

Of course the auto-filter itself must be set before protecting the sheet. The setting `lockAutoFilter(false)` does only enabling the **usage** the auto-filter in protected sheets.

And for using sorting there must be set a range which is enabled for users to edit. This is because while sorting the cell values will be changed since contents of rows and so of all cells in that rows probably must be exchanged while sorting.

In `Excel` GUI this is made via `Review tab` -> `Allow Users to Edit Ranges`. in `apache poi` we have to add a [CTProtectedRange](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTProtectedRange.java) to the [CTWorksheet](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTWorksheet.java).

Note the usage of `CTProtectedRange` needs the full jar of all of the schemas `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar` as mentioned in [faq-N10025](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTProtectedRange;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CreateExcelXSSFProtectedSheetAllowFilteringAndSorting {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  Row row;
  Cell cell;

  row = sheet.createRow(0);
  for (int c = 0 ; c < 4; c++) {
   cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellValue("Field " + (c+1));
  }

  for (int r = 1; r < 10; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0 ; c < 4; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue("Data R" + (r+1) + "C" + (c+1));
   }
  }

  sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:D10"));
  ((XSSFSheet)sheet).lockAutoFilter(false);

  CTProtectedRange protectedRange = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet()
   .addNewProtectedRanges()
   .addNewProtectedRange();
  protectedRange.setName("enableSorting");
  protectedRange.setSqref(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"A1:D10"}));

  ((XSSFSheet)sheet).lockSort(false);

  sheet.protectSheet(""); 

  for (int c = 0 ; c < 4; c++) {
   sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelXSSFProtectedSheetAllowFilteringAndSorting.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: It works, but with CTProtectedRange columns are unlocked. How to enable sorting to locked columns?

Comment: @A M: what do you mean by "columns are unlocked". In the sheet resulting from my code, columns cannot be inserted, moved, or deleted. Or do you mean that the content of the cells in the non-protected area can be changed? But this is necessary to enable sorting. Sorting leads to changing cell contents when rows change their order. How else should sorting be possible?

Comment: As "unlocked" I mean modifiable (not read-only). So, the only way to enable sorting for locked (read-only) columns is to unlock the same columns. Isn't it?