# Enable sorting in protect Sheet Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

After protected the sheet.

```
sheet.protectSheet("");
```

Not able to enable sorting.

The new version of POI. Not have an argument to enable the sortingin a protected sheet. It has only to disable sorting.

```
sheet.lockSort();
```

I tried this also.

```
CTSheetProtection sheetProtection = excelSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection();
        sheetProtection.setSort(false);
```

But this function enables the sorting button in excel sheet. But after I click the A-Z or Z-A I am getting the pop-up. Because of the sheet protection.

I am using this `<version>3.10.1</version>`.
I am using a protection method for the user do not edit some column in sheet.
But I need sorting in a protected sheet.

One more question also.
Is this possible to lock the first row of excel. Because do not sort the title row. 
But I used

```
sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);
```

This will freeze from scrolling, not from the sorting. Please help with these two questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155205/enable-filtering-and-sorting-in-a-protected-sheet-using-apache-poi/50186830#50186830

Comment: Btw.: `apache poi` version `3.10.1` is too old to use. Do using the latest stable version which currently is `4.1.0`.